# How can I draw half of ellipse in SVG?

Tags: svg, ellipse

How can I draw half of ellipse in SVG? What I'm trying to do

```
<path d="M 198, 160 a 50,20 1 1,0 1,0" fill="pink" style="fill:pink;stroke:black;stroke-width:1;"/>
```

Comment: Use an SVG editor such as Inkscape to draw whatever you want.

Comment: try this d attribute: `d="M 198, 160 a 50,20 1 1,0 0,40 z"` Also please read about arcs in svg: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Paths#arcs

Answer (score 3):

You already found the right command for your path; the [elliptical arc curve](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/d#elliptical_arc_curve).

In these examples I created half-ellipses with the same dimensions. You can see the two numbers after the `A` are all 10 and 2. 10 is the x radius and 2 the y radius. The two numbers after `M` are all stating points and the two numbers just before Z are the end points. The three numbers in between (`0 0 0` and `0 0 1`) are different flags. The only one I use here is the sweep-flag that indicates clockwise or anticlockwise.

A usefull tool that I use a lot for creating paths is this: [SvgPathEditor](https://yqnn.github.io/svg-path-editor/).

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 20 8">
  <path transform="translate(0 0)" fill="blue"   d="M 10 0 A 10 2 0 0 0 10 4 Z"/>
  <path transform="translate(10 0)" fill="pink"  d="M  0 0 A 10 2 0 0 1  0 4 Z"/>
  <path transform="translate(0 4)" fill="orange" d="M  0 2 A 10 2 0 0 1 20 2 Z"/>
  <path transform="translate(0 6)" fill="lime"   d="M  0 0 A 10 2 0 0 0 20 0 Z"/>
</svg>
```