# Gap SVG circle/ellipse with vertical linecap edges

Tags: svg

I am drawing an SVG ellipse and I want two gaps, positioned center top and bottom:

```
<ellipse fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width cx="15" cy="15" rx="12.55" ry="13.45" stroke-dasharray="19.65 1.5 39.32 1.5"/>
```

But **I want the gap edges to be vertical**, like if I a straight line was drawn through the un-gapped ellipse:

```
<g stroke-width="1.5">
    <ellipse stroke="black" fill="none" cx="15" cy="15" rx="12.55" ry="13.45"/>
    <path stroke="white" d="M15 35 V30">
</g>
```

I can't do that, because the line is not transparent. The gaps should look like nothing has been drawn there and not alter or overlay the background.

Further unsuccessful experiments:

```
stroke-linecap="square" on example #1
stroke="transparent" for the line in ex. #2.
stroke="transparent" stroke-occupacy="1" for the line in ex. #2.
```

What can I do?

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jamacoe/ujLn630q/149/)

Comment: you can't with an ellipse; draw 2 half circles with a gap in between.

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman in this case it might work, beside the fact, that the top and bottom of the object look too wide, because nothing is 'cut out'. But in general ellipse <> circle. I know how to draw half circles with % in r,  but can I draw half ellipses too?

Comment: STFS: (Search The F\*ne StackOverflow) *"How can I draw half of ellipse in SVG?"*: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71223555/how-can-i-draw-half-of-ellipse-in-svg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a typical case for using a mask. Everything that coincides with the white parts of the mask is drawn as is, everything that coincides with the black parts becomes transparent.

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 40 40" height="90vh">
  <mask id="mask">
    <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="white" />
    <path stroke="black" stroke-width="5" d="M15 35 V0" />
  </mask>
  <ellipse stroke="black" fill="none" stroke-width="1.5"
           mask="url(#mask)"
           cx="15" cy="15" rx="12.55" ry="13.45" />
</svg>
```